# Has anyone submitted an Android app to the Tencent App Store in China successfully from the US?

Tags: android, google-play

Specifically, using the following URL:

https://open.qq.com/eng/reg

It took my hours to get a combination of browser and operating system versions that actually let me upload anything without getting a 301 error. However, even with that success, I cannot, for all my google searching, find out what a "Company License" or "Declaration of Authorization" are nor can I get an APK to upload without getting a 501 error once it's 100% uploaded.

If there's another method to submit Android apps to the Tencent App Store in China, I'd love to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

In a similar predicament trying to get my company's mobile app on Tencent. After some very varied research this afternoon (including ending up on this page), I was able to discern what I *think* are the requirements for Company License and Declaration of Authorization:

- Company License is the logo or brand image to accompany your app
- Declaration of Authorization is a QR code that directs to the iOS version of your app on the Apple App Store

I can't make any promises that these are actually correct, but I'm reasonably confident based on context (Company License asks for .jpg or .png and another user initially attempting upload on the Chinese site provided a file with "logo" in the file name when being directed to try the /eng/reg upload site). I believe a QR code is what they are asking for by "Declaration of Authorization" because Tencent's approach appears to be uploading the Android APK directly to their store, while making the QR code to the Apple App Store through WeChat for iPhone users. Again, piecing that part together from multiple articles.

In return, if you're able to figure out the right combination of buttons to push to actually get your APK uploaded, sharing that process here would be greatly appreciated. I likewise am unable to get anything but a 501 Network Error, and without that, my effort seems pretty much dead in the water since it seems Tencent is generally unresponsive.

Good luck!

Comment: Was wondering if either of you have been able to be successful uploading to Tencent? I'm getting the same 501 error.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, but I'm getting a 302 network error trying to upload a logo there. Maybe if we use a VPN with a chinese IP it could work, not sure, but cound't find any free one. China is another world.